# How to get turn angle, line orientation and line length in ArcMap 9.3.1?

Tags: arcmap, vector, length

I am mapping and analysing animal movements using arcgis 9.3.1 along with Hawthorne Beyer's GME, and am trying to utilise the correlated random walk commands, but in order to do this I need to find out the turn angles, step length and line orientation.
Is there a way to easily do this in arcmap for an entire vector layer? Such as is done with calculating total or portion line length by adding a new field and calculating geometry? 
I am not adept at using scripts, so if the solution requires this, can you also include instruction on how to run it?
Very many thanks in advance,

Comment: Could you please provide an example on how your data exactly looks like? In addition it would be helpful if you define what you mean when talking about turn angle, step length and line orientation. Thanks.

Comment: Hi there, I actually found what I needed with Hawth's Tools in the end, even though it is supposedly not compatible with 9.3. However, if you are still interested, the step length is the distance between each location point, turn angle is an axial measurement of the angle to the next point in relation to the last one, and line orientation is the bearing of the line. The solution to calculating all of these is "Calculate Movement Parameters" in Hawths tools. Shame there is no equivalent in GME as yet...

Answer (score 2):

@Elusival answered their own question in a [comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8300/how-to-get-turn-angle-line-orientation-and-line-length-in-arcmap-9-3-1/227459#comment10237_8300):

> "I actually found what I needed with Hawth's Tools in the
>   end, even though it is supposedly not compatible with 9.3. However, if
>   you are still interested, the step length is the distance between each
>   location point, turn angle is an axial measurement of the angle to the
>   next point in relation to the last one, and line orientation is the
>   bearing of the line. The solution to calculating all of these is
>   "Calculate Movement Parameters" in Hawths tools. Shame there is no
>   equivalent in GME as yet."

This may be addressed in more recent versions of GME as well, or in other tools or scripts